# different resources and manifest in build variant in gradle in android

Tags: android, build

I want to use same source code but different resources and menifest for two different build variant. this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.test.project'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        FV {
            applicationId "com.test.project"
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        AV {
            applicationId "com.test.project"
              versionName "1.0"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.AV {
        manifest.srcFile 'resources/av_res/AndroidManifest.xml'
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'resources/av_res/res']
    }


    sourceSets.FV {
        manifest.srcFile 'resources/fv_res/AndroidManifest.xml'
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'resources/fv_res/res']
    }




}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalytics.jar')
}
```

in this i am getting an error :

> Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugManifest'.
>
> > File 'D:\nitin\projects\FV\SFV\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When using productFlavors you can create specific folders for them. In your case you can create the folder "FV" and "AV" beside your "main" folder.

it should look something like this:

```
src/
   main/
      AndroidManifest.xml
      res/
         ...
   FV/
      AndroidManifest.xml
      res/
         ...
   AV/
      AndroidManifest.xml
      res/
         ...
```

This way you will be able to remove the code in your build.gradle where you specify certain directories since the build system will automatically detect them.